# Events on items in databound repeater don't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Source First:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Bars" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Name" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Description" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="AddBar" Text="Add Bar" runat="server" onclick="AddBar_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Widget { get; set; }
        public string Cog { get; set; }
        public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Foo Foo
        {
            get
            {
                var retval = Session["Foo"];
                if (retval == null)
                {
                    retval = new Foo();
                    Session["Foo"] = retval;
                }
                return retval == null ? new Foo() : (Foo)retval;
            }
            set
            {
                Session["Foo"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var f = new Foo() { Bars = new List<Bar>(), Cog = "Cog one", Widget = "Widget Master" };
                f.Bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = "Bar one", Description = "hello." });
                Foo = f;
                Bind();
            }
        }

        protected void Bars_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item != null && e.Item.DataItem != null)
            {
                var b = e.Item.DataItem as Bar;
                var Name = e.Item.FindControl("Name") as TextBox;
                var Description = e.Item.FindControl("Description") as TextBox;
                Name.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Name_TextChanged);
            }
        }

        protected void Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Name = sender as TextBox;
            var listItem = Name.Parent as RepeaterItem;
            var f = Foo;
            var b = f.Bars[listItem.ItemIndex];
            b.Name = Name.Text;
            Foo = f;
            Bind();
        }

        protected void AddBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var f = Foo;
            f.Bars.Add(new Bar());
            Foo = f;
            Bind();
        }

        private void Bind()
        {
            Bars.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(Bars_ItemDataBound);
            Bars.DataSource = Foo.Bars;
            Bars.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I haven't used databinding in years but so I thought I'd refresh my memory, but I can't get this to work. When I start the app, I see one entry with the values I expect. If I click add, new values show up and the existing value is preserved.

**Here is the problem: When I change the value in the Name textbox, I can see the page refresh, but my Name_TextChanged event doesn't break. Since it doesn't fire, the value goes back to what it was before.**

Comment: Your EventHandler `void Name_TextChanged` is private. make it protected and see if it works now ?

Comment: No luck. Updated the question to match.

Comment: I can see in the request that the new values are being POSTed to the server too.

Comment: MSDN Clearly shows that asp controls can be contained in a template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx

Comment: Well. I see you are re-binding in the `AddBar_Click`. DataBinding should be done once i think, when not in postback (what you do correctly in Page_Load)

Comment: @DidierG. - It is necessary to rebind when adding or removing items from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach OnTextChanged event in aspx. The following codes work.

```
protected void Bars_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null && e.Item.DataItem != null)
    {
        var b = e.Item.DataItem as Bar;
        var Name = e.Item.FindControl("Name") as TextBox;
        var Description = e.Item.FindControl("Description") as TextBox;
        // Commented
        // Name.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Name_TextChanged);
    }
}

<asp:TextBox ID="Name" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Name_TextChanged" /> 

<asp:TextBox ID="Description" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' 
runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Name_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: Well, I guess I was making it more complicated than it had to be. Thanks @Win

Comment: IF anyone has a reference for this that would be great too.